# TFS não foi possível localizar parte do caminho

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server

Estou tentando fazer o check-in de um projeto para o meu repositório no visual studio online (Team Fundation Service). Mas estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750781/tfs-checkin-error-could-not-find-file

Comment: Você tentou fazer o commit no console?
No console usando o comando git status, qual o retorno?

Comment: @egomesbrandao Opa, obrigado pela sugestão, na verdade não estou usando `git` e sim `TFS`. Eu já identifiquei o problema e corrigi. O problema é que o arquivo `FoxCcoManagerDatabase.sln` não estava mais no local indicado no erro.

Comment: Desculpa, Matheus... realmente não vi escrito acima check-in, que só usado no TFVC e não no Git

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva como você identificou e corrigiu o problema, poste uma reposta. Desta forma a pergunta sairá da fila sem resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O arquivo `FoxCcoManagerDatabase.sln` não estava mais no local indicado pelo erro. Bastou remover o arquivo através da janela **Control Source Explorer**.